# What would I type using the pipe operator to find/list only IPv4 address?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

When I type `ipconfig`, what should I type to list only the IPv4 address?

```
C:\Users\nate\CLI_Test> ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::953b:5e50:3b8f:5dc2%3
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: ipconfig | findstr /i "ipv4"
it will find the string whcih contains the "IPv4" and will output it on the cmd.